# How can I return to the 3D view after rendering?

Tags: interface, shortcut

In blender, after I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render, the view changes. Is there a button or key that I can press to go back to the *3d view*?

Comment: Rendering does not change the model at all, rendering is merely refers to generating a 2D image of the model. You can return to the 3D view by pressing `Escape`.

Comment: Pressing ESC will do the trick.

Comment: Just hit F11 on your keyboard. When it is rendered, hit F11 to go back to your 3D animating workspace.

Answer (score 24):

A completed render doesn't hog the memory on your computer anymore. To get back to the 3D View from the Image Editor window, either press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, or just change the view.

[image: Go to 3D View]

I'm surprised nobody else answered it using the most simple way of changing viewport windows. :P

Comment: I've found that you can either press `ESC` (always takes you to 3d view or `F11` (toggles render view). #blender2-77

Comment: A note for macOS users, F11 toggles view desktop, so just escape works here.

Answer (score 5):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> should do this by default and in addition to [WChargin's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3728/12), another way about this is to go to the *Render* context in the *Properties* panel and under *Render*, change *Display* to *New Window*. This will have your renders appear in a separate ***window***, one that you can close without exiting Blender or switching views.

[image]

Comment: "without ... switching views" yeah, but you have to switch windows. I find F11 quicker than Alt-Tab, and it doesn't interfere with my workflow as much: if I switch from Blender to the Render Result and then to Chrome, a single Alt-Tab will take me back to the Render Result, and then I need two to get back to Blender... this is stuff I don't want to have to think about! xD

Comment: @WChargin Who said anything about shortcuts ;). For a new user learning Blender, I would like to think having a separate window (that you can close without the risk of losing everything) can be useful if not less confusing than having your viewport switch to an image.

Comment: `Shift + F5` can be used to quickly jump to the 3D view from any editor.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking about returning to the model view after seeing a render.

Usually, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will do the trick.

If this doesn't work, try <kbd>F11</kbd>, or *Window > Show/Hide Render View*.

If this still doesn't work, you can do the following:

- Save the file.
- Open the default file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for a new file).
- Open the old file **without the *Load UI* setting checked** in the *Open Blender File* window. This will reload the file with the default user interface:

  [image: Location of *Load UI* in the interface]