# Toggle Render Image / UV Image

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

this is a basic question but I can't find any answer. It's driving me (a bit) mad.

When I press F12 the UV/Image-editor becomes my render-editor but how can I change it back to an UV-editor?

:)

Comment: If you want to stop render result from appearing in UV editor where you edit UVs change Display setting in render settings, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3729/1245

Answer (score 1):

It *is* your UV editor, it's just showing your rendered image.

See the image popup at the bottom of the pane, that says "Render Result"? Just click that, and select another image.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing which is bothering me. It's kinda empty :(


https://abload.de/img/unbenannt357od9.jpg

https://abload.de/img/unbenannt47sqa9.jpg

Comment: Press the "X" to switch back from the rendered image.

Comment: @B.Y.O.B.: That works, although sometimes I want to switch to a different image instead of an empty editor.

Comment: @MatthieuO.: It looks like your pane header bar is gone. Is it there, but not in your screenshot?

Comment: I linked two images but the bar is only missing in the first screenshot but luckily I don't have any problem with the UV View itself.
I am linking again the image that is bothering me: the rendered image.
The Render Result is empty (and believe me: I created marked Seams and unwrapped the UVs)

https://abload.de/img/unbenannt4473qs2.jpg


Btw. Pressing X didn't work out.

Comment: What happens if you render the image again?